# Are the sets whose convex hull surface admits multiple representations a shy set of sets?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, convex-analysis, convex-hulls

Consider a compact subset $A$ of $R^n$. Let me call $A$ *special* if any point $x$ that is on the boundary of $\textsf{conv.hull}(A)$ admits a unique representation as a convex combination of points in $A$.

My question is: Are "almost all" such compact subsets *special*?

If $A$ is finite, I think an argument by induction works: At the addition of a new point, the surface of the existing convex hull is $n-1$-dimensional, and so there is zero probability that the new point falls into this surface.

But to show the same result for (uncountably) infinite sets A (or at least A's generated by reasonably behaved parametric curves of one parameter), I am lost.
From looking online, it seems that prevalence ([Hunt, 1992](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9210220.pdf)) seems to be the right concept. I am however unfamiliar with the techniques, and cannot readily come up with a proof, but I'm hoping that maybe such a result is already known, if only one knows the right language?

Comment: I don't understand.  By "extremal" do you mean an extreme point?  But an extreme point of the convex hull of $A$ is always a member of $A$, and can't be a nontrivial convex combination of any other points of $A$.  Or do you just mean a boundary point?

Comment: I mean a point that solves $\arg\max_{x\in \textsf{conv.hull}(A)} \psi'x$ for some $\psi\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Sorry... I think boundary point is the right name. I will update the question right now.

Comment: The definitions of "shy" and "prevalent" require a complete metric linear space.  Nonempty compact subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ do form a complete metric space with the Hausdorff metric, but it's not a linear space.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. So actually I'm not interested in all compact subsets, I just thought that would be a more general question. In my specific application, the sets A are given as the image of a parametric curve $a:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^n$, and it's fine if I have to assume some extra properties such as continuity or single-peakedness in each dimension. Not 100% sure if that's a complete metric linear space now, but maybe there's hope?

Comment: Your argument in the finite case is wrong. When you add a new point previously existing points could lose unique representation. (The "measure zero" conclusion should still be true, though.)

Comment: The continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R^n$ form a complete metric linear space, and maybe the corresponding set is prevalent there.

Comment: @NikWeaver Thanks for pointing that out. I think what would work is to say that there is zero probability that the new point falls into one of the $n-1$ limiting half-spaces. That would also imply that any existing boundary point either maintains a unique representation or stops being on the boundary.